# Insert as many rows as count on other table returns

Tags: mysql, trigger

Hello I have three tables in my MySQL-DB

```
Project:
id | name
1  | project1
2  | project2

KPI:
id | name
1  | build_status
2  | satisfaction

ProjectKPIData:
id | kpi_id | project_id | value
1  | 1      | 1          | 2
2  | 1      | 2          | 0
3  | 2      | 1          | 1
4  | 2      | 2          | 1
```

Now I am trying to add a trigger to the `Project`-table. If a new project gets added it should insert as many rows into `ProjectKPIData` as there are KPI's and also insert the id of them. So after I add a new project the table `ProjectKPIData` should look like this (the project id 3 is for the newly created project):

```
ProjectKPIData:
id | kpi_id | project_id | value
1  | 1      | 1          | 2
2  | 1      | 2          | 0
3  | 2      | 1          | 1
4  | 2      | 2          | 1
5  | 1      | 3          | 0
6  | 2      | 3          | 0
```

Is there a specific MySQL query I can acomplish this? Im pretty new to MySQL-Databases and I couldn't find a way of doing this while searching online.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query.

```
INSERT INTO ProjectKPIData (`kpi_id`,`project_id`,`value`) SELECT k.id,NEW.id,0 FROM KPI k;
```